# RoboEarth on Ubuntu oneiric: Compilation errors

Tags: roboearth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

After following all steps to install roboearth (http://www.ros.org/wiki/roboearth) with ros-electric in Ubuntu 11.10 (oneiric), I still have the following compilation errors when I do **rosmake roboearth**:

- roboearth/object_scanning/re_kinect_object_detector/src/recognitionmodel.cpp:457:10: error: ‘class boost::filesystem3::path’ has no member called ‘native_file_string’, an similar ones
- roboearth/object_scanning/ar_bounding_box/src/ar_kinect.cpp:479:63: error: taking address of temporary [-fpermissive], repeated several times

Note that I had to translate error messages into English, so probably they're not the same text you would have if you try to reproduce the error.

Thanks!

Regards,

Enrique

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12273/roboearth-on-ubuntu-oneiric:-compilation-errors/) by [Enrique](https://answers.ros.org/users/244/enrique/) on ROS Answers with karma: 834 on 2011-12-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This looks like the transition between boost filesystem version 2 and 3.  Roboearth probably needs a patch.  Another similar question http://answers.ros.org/question/1459/boostfilesystem-version-issues

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-12-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1